# On Azure AD where do you see failed application login attempts

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

In Azure AD I have setup Two applications for a client and a server. Server has permissions for access and client can access it using a Client Id and Client Secret.

Every time the new request goes throguh I can see the JWT being set on the client but I can not monitor the event in AD. Where do I see the logins from the Client App to the server App?

If I change the Client ID to be incorrect the server correctly fails but where does is the event reported?

have turned on diagnostics ogs and monitor but can not see anything their yet.

Comment: Is that you want to know who login?

Answer (score 0):

You can check these details in Azure Active Directory, Audit logs. By default, you can find the Audit logs in `Azure Active Directory -> Monitoring` section of Azure Active Directory.

> **Note**: You should be assigned with the role of Global Administrator,
> Security Administrator, Security Reader, Report Reader or Global
> Reader to have access to this Audit logs.

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) for more details